# what events can you pass to jQuery on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone have a link to a list of ALL events that can be passed to **jQuery .on()**?

Here are a few, but I cant seem to find a definitive list.

- click
- mouseenter
- mouseleave
- contextmenu (works on right click, and tap and hold with Android (not iOS))
- focus
- blur
- focusin
- focusout
- scroll

I'm looking for Android/iOS touch events in particular.

**Thanks!**

**EDIT 1:** So I think the real question i'm asking is what events are standard across all browsers/devices?

Comment: Well you can register custom events so I'm going to say: infinite.

Comment: Have a look at http://learn.jquery.com/events/, especially http://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-events/.

Comment: @user1506980 that is the one true answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to realise that the important question is not: **What events can you pass to `jQuery.on()`?** Because you can technically pass **any event** to that method.

The real question is, what events does the **browser/device fire?** Obviously, some events — as the ones you listed — are a standard, but some browsers will surprise you by not firing some events or by having their own custom events.

You can find a pretty extensive list at the MDN:

<kbd>[**Events reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events)</kbd>

But keep in mind that the point is that you can also define your own custom events, [trigger them](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), and bind event listeners to them.

Comment: So I think the real question i'm asking is what events are standard across **all** browsers/devices?

Comment: Take a look at this for a comparison table: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/

Comment: As everything in the web world, unfortunately, there is no such thing as **across all browser/devices**. You can rely pretty strongly on some of them.

Comment: The MDN link above lists more standard events you *should be able to rely upon* because they are in the official spec. This doesn't give you any assurance (as nothing in the spec does) but should give you some pretty good guidelines, along with the quirksmode table and some thorough testing.

Answer (score 1):

For touch screen devices you will have the following events:

- `touchstart`
- `touchend`
- `touchmove`
- `touchcancel`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery mobile?  The events are listed here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Answer (score 0):

Google **DOM Events**, get [MDN Event Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events).

You may be particularly interested in the [TouchEvent subclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent).

Of course, you can bind any custom event using `.on` and trigger any custom event with `.trigger`, so the real answer is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

You can register **any** event names. Whether they will be called is another question… Custom events can be manually triggered, and there are [many that are triggered natively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events) in the DOM. For some of them, jQuery has special [shorthand methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

> I'm looking for Android/iOS touch events in particular.

Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Touch_events then, or the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/).

Answer (score 0):

All jQuery events. 
Here are lists of [keyboard events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) and [mouse events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/).